# Permissions issue using MSBuild extension pack and IIS7 tasks

Tags: iis-7, msbuild, msbuildextensionpack

im trying to use the iis7 web task in the extension pack. I cant successful use the task(with my god level admin access), but my issue is that i cant use it with the user that must run it (service user).

```
<Target Name="CheckForSite">
<Message Text="Site:              $(Site)" />
<Message Text="Application:       $(Application)" />
<Message Text="Server:            $(Server)" />
<Message Text="PhysicalPath:      $(PhysicalPath)"/>

<!-- Check if the site exists -->
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Web.Iis7Website TaskAction="CheckExists"
                                       Name="$(Site)"
                                       MachineName="$(Server)"
                                       >
  <Output TaskParameter="Exists" PropertyName="SiteExists"/>
</MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Web.Iis7Website>

<Message Text="Site Exists: $(SiteExists)" Condition="$(SiteExists)"/>
<Message Text="Site does not exist: $(SiteExists)" Condition="(!$(SiteExists))"/>
```

I get the error: 
error : UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for remote component with CLSID {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344} from machine  failed due to the following error: 80070005

Answer (score 1):

It is access denied exception. Try to add Username="username" UserPassword="password" properties into the MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Web.Iis7Website task. User should be admin on the target machine.

In my case I had a problem with domain communication. My server is in the different domain as my user's domain. It was fixed by our infrastructure team. I found this issue in the event log. Check event logs first for any related issues.

Comment: Hi Ludwo, yeah i tried that already. Even if specofy and that user is added as an admin i get UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for remote component with CLSID {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344} from machine <remotehost> failed due to the following error: 80070005 <remotehost>. thanks for the answer though.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, what's the solution for this?